# Issue with splitting 2 dates from a string

Tags: c#, .net, razor, split

I'm trying to pull two dates out of a string which I get from a form. The string looks a little like this:

03/18/2013 - 03/23/2013

I've made an attempt to split these values out, but I am having problems with doing a split on " - "

Here's my code so far:

```
    string daterange = Request.Form["daterange"];
    string [] arr = daterange.Split(new Char[] {' '});
    string bookedfrom = arr[0];
    string bookedto = arr[1];
```

However, this gives me the following two values:

value 1 = 03/18/2013
value 2 = -

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is splitting on space, not on hyphen.

Comment: Check your array length, you should have 3 items. 1 the first date, 2 the - and 3 the other date.

Comment: `string bookedfrom = arr.First();
string bookedto = arr.Last();`

Comment: thanks fantastik78, indeed it works if i used string bookedto = arr[2];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [overload of `String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) that takes a string array instead of a character array, but it requires a second parameter.  Try

```
string [] arr = daterange.Split(new string[] {" - "},StringSplitOptions.None);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative (since you have just *two* pieces) you can use `Substring` instead of `Split`:

```
  String daterange = Request.Form["daterange"];

  String bookedfrom = daterange.Substring(0, daterange.IndexOf(" - "));
  String bookedto = daterange.Substring(daterange.IndexOf(" - ") + " - ".Length);
```